# Sklearn: Is there a way to define a specific score type to pipeline?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pipeline

I can do this:

```
model=linear_model.LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs',max_iter=10000)
kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=number_splits,shuffle=True, random_state=random_state)
scalar = StandardScaler()
pipeline = Pipeline([('transformer', scalar), ('estimator', model)])
results = model_selection.cross_validate(pipeline, X, y, cv=kfold, scoring=score_list,return_train_score=True)
```

where score_list can be something like `['accuracy','balanced_accuracy','precision','recall','f1']`.

I also can do this:

```
kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=number_splits,shuffle=True, random_state=random_state)
scalar = StandardScaler()
pipeline = Pipeline([('transformer', scalar), ('estimator', model)])
for i, (train, test) in enumerate(kfold.split(X, y)):
    pipeline.fit(self.X[train], self.y[train])
    pipeline.score(self.X[test], self.y[test])
```

However, I am not able to change the score type for pipeline in the last line. How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`score` method is always `accuracy` for classification and `r2` score for regression. There is no parameter to change that. It comes from the `Classifiermixin` and `RegressorMixin`.

Instead, when we need other scoring options, we have to import it from [`sklearn.metrics`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html) like the following.

```py
from sklearn.metrics import balanced_accuracy

y_pred = pipeline.predict(self.X[test])
balanced_accuracy(self.y_test, y_pred)
```

Comment: Now `balanced_accuracy_score`